# Dynamic select in nested form rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, cocoon-gem

How do js get the selected value in a dropdown and pass it to the controller so that it returns a list of names for the other dropdown?

What I've done so far:
salmonellas.js

```
$(function () {
   $('body').on('change', "#mode_change", function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedText) {
          $.get('/salmonellas/find_stages?mode_title='+ selectedText, function(selectedText) {                
            return $(selectedText).html();
          });
        }
    });
});
```

salmonellas/form.html.erb

```
<div class="process_salmonellas">
    <% f.simple_fields_for :process_salmonellas do |process_salmonella| %>
        <%= render 'process_salmonella_fields', :f => process_salmonella %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

salmonellas/_process_salmonella_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="mode_change" id="mode_change">
    <%= f.collection_select :title, Mode.order(:name), :id, :name, class: 'mode_change', id:'mode_change', include_blank: true, "data-content": :mode_id%>
</div>
<h4>Stage</h4>
<div class="stage">
    <% f.simple_fields_for :stages do |stage| %>
        <%= render 'stage_fields', :f => stage %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

salmonella/_stage_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.grouped_collection_select :title, Mode.order(:name), :steps, :name, :id, :name, class: "step_selection" %>
</div>
```

salmonellas_controller.rb

```
def find_stages
    @mode = Mode.where("name = ?", params[:mode_title])
    @steps = @mode.steps
end
```

Is looking for another model, why the fields have to be pre-registered. I'm using cocoon to let it nested.

**Updating**

salmonellas/_process_salmonella_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.collection_select :title, Mode.order(:name), :id, :name, class: 'mode_change', id:'mode_change', include_blank: true, "data-content": :mode_id%>
</div>
<h4>Stage</h4>
<div class="stage">
    <% f.simple_fields_for :stages do |stage| %>
        <%= render 'stage_fields', :f => stage %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**Updating 2**

salmonellas/_process_salmonella_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.collection_select :title, Mode.order(:name), :id, :name, id:'mode_change', include_blank: true %>
</div>
```

salmonellas.js

```
$(function () {
   $('body').on('change', ".mode_change", function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        if (selectedText) {
          $.get('/salmonellas/find_stages?mode_title='+ selectedText, function(selectedText) {                
            return $(selectedText).html();
          });
        }
    });
});
```

**Updating 3**

salmonellas.js

```
 $(function () {
   $(document).on('change', "#mode_change", function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();
        alert("Selected Text: " + selectedText);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique on your DOM. You are duplicating them for `div` and `select` tag. First change them and use this to get the value of selected option

```
$(document).on('change', ".mode_change", function () {
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
      ...
```

Comment: @E.D.B. not sure if you understood this answer completely: you have to _remove_ all duplicate id's, not just add the classes. An id is supposed to be unique over the whole page, so do not use them for any repeating elements. It will render, but upon selecting or submitting a form results will be unexpected.

Comment: I updated again, if not that, I did not understand what you meant.

Comment: As per to your last update you're good to go. Now try the script `$(document).on('change', "#mode_change", function () {`

Comment: Can you explain to me why to be "document" and not "body"?

Comment: The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

Comment: Ok, I put an alert after the selection in the dropdown, to test if it was entering the function, but the alert does not appear.

Comment: can you add a test snippet ?

Comment: You have no class of `mode_change` on select now.  Use. `$(document).on('change', "#mode_change", function () {` check difference. I explicitly mentioned to use `Id` as selector. It would be better if you study it first.

Comment: I forgot to update here in the stack, but in my code it is looking for the id, I updated again.